# How to use xsi namespace in XML created by Python (2.5.4) etree

Tags: python, xml, namespaces

I have been frequently using Python for interfaces; this time I can't find a solution for a "tiny" problem with a XML namespace:

This XML that is wanted:

```
<alternate xsi:type="gallery" fragment="123">
```

The problematic part is :   `xsi:type`

This> `etree.Subelement(alternates,"alternate",{"type":"gallery","fragment":"123"})`

Would return: `< alternate type="gallery" fragment="123" >`

So my question is how to get xsi namespace. I tried various things with namespace declarations but no success.

The root element requires somehow the same:
`< article xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >`

I managed to get this only:
`< xsi:article xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >`

Using syntax: 
`articles = etree.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}article"  )`

Comment: Partly solved:   Solution for root element found: 

'articles = etree.Element("articles", **nsmap={'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}**)'

Still looking for a solution to get this XML element:
*'<alternate xsi:type="gallery" fragment="123">'*

Comment: Got it solved using this:

        try:
            register_namespace = etree.register_namespace
        except AttributeError:
            def register_namespace(prefix, uri):
                _namespace_map[uri] = prefix
        register_namespace('xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")